# How to scale up Spring webservices?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, tomcat, spring-ws

What are the different methods available to scale up a single webservice deployed in a tomcat container on a powerful h/w node?

Does it make sense to clone the WS and deploy multiple instances of this WS with in the container and somehow balance it (not probable, given how a webservice is a unique endpoint)? Or, should tomcat run multiple processes on different ports (even here, the WS client has only one url to hit)?

Comment: The question as is, is too broad. There are entire blogs and papers related to this. I'd presume that the ideal solution would depend on your current architecture and scope.

Comment: I don't need a definite answer. I want to understand what the different top level strategies. Scaling out is simple to understand - your load balancer works at IP level. But how is "Scaling up" usually handled?

Comment: You can refer the links below for horizontal scale up. 1. http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/loadbalancers.html   2.                                                      https://dzone.com/articles/how-configure-tomcatjboss-and

Comment: @Raghu thanks, that helps as a start. So, it looks like, I will have to run multiple tomcat instances on different ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to scale? Because a single instance can't do the work.

What are the limiting factors? CPU, Memory, other resources.

If you are hitting a per-process limitation, for example suppose there's a maximum memory size for a single JVM, then it may make sense to start another Tomcat instance on the same machine. In that case, as you say you will need to use different ports. From your comment, I think you refer to this pattern as scaling-**up**.

More likely you are hitting a per-machine limit, just not enough CPU. In which case you need to start a new instance on another machine. This has the added possible benefit of giving additional resilience. You lose a machine, you still have a service running elsewhere. This you refer to as scaling-**out**.

In either case you need some form of IP sprayer or load balancer in front of the instances so that your client doesn't need to "know" about the individual cluster members.

I don't really see much distinction between the two cases. From the client perspective, just hit the sprayer. From the server perspective when scalin-up you need to ensure that resources don't clash. Ports are one obvious example, but also you need to consider things like log files. Usually it's worth coming up with a set of naming conventions and resource structures so that it's easy to identify what belongs to what.

As getting all these configurations right can be a error-prone it's also worth investing in some scripting so that setting up an instance is a simple, reproducible task.